# "routing back" through a wireless hotspot does not work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, wifi, routing

I have a Linux device running a wireless hotspot:

```
my laptop (LAN only: 192.168.1.100)
  |
 LAN
  |
wireless hotspot laptop (LAN: 192.168.1.101, wireless hotspot: 10.42.0.1, VMs: 10.254.2.x)
  |
wireless printer (wifi: 10.42.0.67)
```

From my laptop, I'm able to ping/connect to the wireless hotspot laptop using its LAN IP (192.168.1.101).

I'm also able to ping/connect to its wireless hotspot IP (10.42.0.1) after I add the following routing on my laptop:

`ip route add to 10.42.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.101`

I am also able to ping/connect to the VMs on the laptop if I add the following routing rule:

`ip route add to 10.254.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.101`

However, pinging/connecting to anything within the wireless network (10.42.0.0/24) - no dice, getting "Destination Port Unreachable":

```
# ping 10.42.0.67
PING 10.42.0.67 (10.42.0.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
^C
--- 10.42.0.67 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1001ms
```

Adding the following MASQUERADE rule on the wireless hotspot laptop allows my laptop to communicate i.e. with 8.8.8.8:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.100 -j MASQUERADE
```

tcpdump on the wireless hotspot laptop indicates the traffic from my laptop to 8.8.8.8 is going through it:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=44.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=46.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.425/45.668/46.912/1.243 ms
```

Still, connecting to 10.42.0.67 (wireless printer behind the wireless hotspot) - no dice (below, tcpdump on the wireless hotspot):

```
01:25:20.901823 enp1s0 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37541, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.100 > 10.42.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 216, seq 16, length 64
01:25:20.902038 enp1s0 Out IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 11555, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 112)
    192.168.1.101 > 192.168.1.100: ICMP 10.42.0.67 protocol 1 port 12067 unreachable, length 92
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 37541, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.100 > 10.42.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 216, seq 16, length 64
```

Is wifi anything special that Linux does not want to route nor NAT into it?

Current nftables rules are as follows; `lxd` part relates to containers running there; `nm-shared-wlp2s0` relates to wireless hotspot; there are no iptables rules (without my MASQUERADE in an example above):

```
table inet lxd {
        chain pstrt.lxdbr0 {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.254.2.0/24 ip daddr != 10.254.2.0/24 masquerade
        }

        chain fwd.lxdbr0 {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                ip version 4 oifname "lxdbr0" accept
                ip version 4 iifname "lxdbr0" accept
        }

        chain in.lxdbr0 {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "lxdbr0" tcp dport 53 accept
                iifname "lxdbr0" udp dport 53 accept
                iifname "lxdbr0" icmp type { destination-unreachable, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept
                iifname "lxdbr0" udp dport 67 accept
        }

        chain out.lxdbr0 {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                oifname "lxdbr0" tcp sport 53 accept
                oifname "lxdbr0" udp sport 53 accept
                oifname "lxdbr0" icmp type { destination-unreachable, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept
                oifname "lxdbr0" udp sport 67 accept
        }
}
table ip nm-shared-wlp2s0 {
        chain nat_postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 ip daddr != 10.42.0.0/24 masquerade
        }

        chain filter_forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 10.42.0.0/24 oifname "wlp2s0" ct state { established, related } accept
                ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 iifname "wlp2s0" accept
                iifname "wlp2s0" oifname "wlp2s0" accept
                iifname "wlp2s0" reject
                oifname "wlp2s0" reject
        }
}
```

Comment: You should inspect thoroughly your hotspot laptop firewall rules. Or add them in the question ( `iptables-save -c` or `nft list ruleset` if something also uses nftables).

Comment: Added `nft list ruleset` output; `iptables-save -c` are empty (when without my MASQUERADE in an example above).

Comment: Do you have any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

From the naming, your system has two tools applying firewall rules: LXD (which doesn't interfere: nothing drops or rejects) and an other tool, which you will have to figure out from the naming it chose: table `nm-shared-wlp2s0`.

You'll have to figure out what tool this could be and configure this tool to add an exception to reach your printer's network from your other LAN.

Meanwhile among a lot of equivalent choices, you can do this manually. For example enable incoming packets to this LAN from the other LAN:

```
nft insert rule nm-shared-wlp2s0 filter_forward ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 ip daddr 10.42.0.0/24 oifname "wlp2s0" ct state new accept
```

This will have to be done each time the tool re configures its firewall rules (hoping that it won't "actively" remove your rule).

---

Beside, this table  (and thus the tool which created it) doesn't follow best practice to drop invalid packets before rejecting packets. Rejecting (rather than dropping) invalid packets can lead to problems especially with reordered packets. See the explanation following this quote from [*iptables*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8##REJECT_(IPv4-specific)) (but also affecting *nftables*) for details:

> Warning: You should not indiscriminately apply the REJECT target to
> packets whose connection state is classified as INVALID; instead, you
> should only DROP these.

Optionally and after the previous command, this should be added too:

```
nft insert rule nm-shared-wlp2s0 filter_forward index 2 ct state invalid drop
```

to prevent flow disruption which could happen with reordered packets (Wifi could create this condition).

Note that every table present in *nftables* gives the opportunity to have hooked chains that can affect a packet. Even if one table's chain accepted a packet, it can still be dropped in an other chain hooking to the same place: here there are two chains hooking in the Netfilter's filter/forward: `inet lxd fwd.lxdbr0` and `ip nm-shared-wlp2s0 filter_forward`: each of them gets an opportunity to drop a packet.